# datanode available: 0 when installing hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to install hadoop-0.23.5 on single node, but after starting namenode and datanode, it shows that the datanode available is 0:

```
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 KB) Present Capacity: 0 (0 KB) DFS Remaining: 0 (0 KB) DFS Used: 0 (0 KB) DFS Used%: ï¿½% Under replicated blocks: 0 Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0 Missing blocks: 0

Datanodes available: 0 (0 total, 0 dead)
```

I checked the datanode log file and this is the error:

```
FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.io.IOException: Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
```

I set dfs.namenode.rpc-address in hdfs-site.xml and I don't understand what the problem is. does anybody know how could i fix this problem.

Comment: Can you post the content of your core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml?
And also output of "netstat -alnp| grep 9000" ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2595) which affected versions 0.23

What you need to do is update `fs.default.name` in core-default.xml

Comment: i set fs.default.name as "hdfs://localhost:9000", i also changed it to "hdfs://n1:9000", but it doesn't solve the problem. i have single node and /etc/hosts is set as:                               127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
192.168.186.139 n1

Comment: Did you restart your cluster after changing this value? You can try to put it in core-site.xml also.

Comment: yes i restart the cluster, any other suggestion? how could i set hosts in core-site.xml? what is the value?